# To test the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\log n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Test the convergence of $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\log n}$$ using comparison test.Since the answer is given as convergent ,I tried using $b_{n}=\frac{1}{n^2}$ but failed since
$$\frac{1}{n^2\log n} \gt \frac{1}{n^2}$$

What other series can I use to prove this?

Comment: You must swap inequality.

Comment: @JohnWatsonThe inequality is correct right?

Comment: No, it is not, you must reverse it.

Comment: @PiGamma, $\log n\gt1$ for $n\ge3$, so the inequality points the other way for $n\gt2$.

Comment: $n^2\log n > n^2$ as soon as $n>2$, so $\frac{1}{n^2\log n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @rogerl reverse it

Comment: @rogerl, I think you need to edit your comment!

Comment: You could also use limit test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @JohnWatson I checked with wolfram alpha.got it now..but then why is my calculator showing $16\log4=9.6329$ instead of $22.1807$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be $$\frac{1}{n^2\log(n)}\le \frac{1}{n^2}$$ since we have
$$1<\log(n)$$ for $n\geq 3$

Comment: thank you for your hint!